# Recording Multiple Rows of Data from Table Insertion Using Trigger

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

I tried creating a trigger to store the data manipulations done on my `Food` table inside another table called `FoodTriggerTable`. When I insert only one row of data, I can record the data manipulation well in `FoodTriggerTable`. However, when I insert multiple rows at once, I only store the information of the first row of data. I have the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertFoodTrigger ON Food
AFTER INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @FoodID varchar(5);
    DECLARE @FoodName nvarchar(50);
    DECLARE @FoodDesc nvarchar(200);
    DECLARE @FoodPrice money;
    DECLARE @InsertAction varchar(200);
    DECLARE @InsertActionTime datetime;
    DECLARE @Amount int;

    SELECT @FoodID = i.FoodID FROM INSERTED i;
    SELECT @FoodName = i.FoodName FROM INSERTED i;
    SELECT @FoodDesc = i.FoodDesc FROM INSERTED i;
    SELECT @FoodPrice = i.FoodPrice FROM INSERTED i;
    SELECT @Amount = COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED i;

    SET @InsertAction = 'You''ve inserted ' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), @Amount) + ' data into ''Food'' table';

    INSERT INTO FoodTriggerTable (FoodID, FoodName, FoodDesc, FoodPrice, InsertAction, InsertActionTime)
    VALUES (@FoodID, @FoodName, @FoodDesc, @FoodPrice, @InsertAction, GETDATE());
GO
```

And I tried the following `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO Food
VALUES  ('CH006', 'Dummy Data 1', 'Dummy data', '0', '34'),
        ('CH007', 'Dummy Data 2', 'Dummy data', '0', '75');
```

How do I fix my trigger so that it also records the second row of data manipulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to think set based - `inserted` is a table, with a row for each record inserted or updated. Just use it as you would a normal table - don't try and convert it to procedural programming e.g.

```
INSERT INTO FoodTriggerTable (FoodID, FoodName, FoodDesc, FoodPrice, InsertAction, InsertActionTime)
  select FoodId, FoodName, FoodDesc, FoodPrice, null, getdate()
  from Inserted
```

Note: Not sure what InsertAction you want when its 1 per row now - up to you.

Edit: Procedural is actually the correct term. When doing stuff in T-SQL you are generally manipulating sets of data, which is whats its designed to do, given its a database programming language. So generally you try to frame and solve the problem in terms of sets of data. This is quite apparent when writing a trigger because and insert/update/delete could involve any number of records and you have to handle that. You can of course use cursors and loops to drop back to procedural programming but performance is going to suffer. There are many articles about this out there, here is an example https://www.sqlshack.com/introduction-set-based-vs-procedural-programming-approaches-t-sql/

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertFoodTrigger ON Food
AFTER INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO FoodTriggerTable (FoodID, FoodName, FoodDesc, FoodPrice, InsertAction, InsertActionTime)
    SELECT FoodID, FoodName, FoodDesc, FoodPrice, 'You''ve inserted ' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted)) + ' data into ''Food'' table', GETDATE()
    FROM inserted
GO
```